# How to transfer balance from Geth account to an actual place?

Tags: go-ethereum

If I only created an account using Geth, but haven't created wallet anywhere (I'm new to mining), and actually got some Ether, is this Ether really exist and I can somehow use it? Or if I haven't created a wallet before it's lost? (it shows 5 when I type web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase), "ether"))

**Edit: I only started doing it for fun, didn't really think I'd actually get some Ether so yes.. I am still learning things about Ethereum, so every help is appreciated, even if for you it seems simple, thanks

Comment: Just curious, how much time did you mine to get ether?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed if you running geth (that is a wallet) on the mainnet and that command returns 5, then you are the proud owner of 5 ethers!

You can send any fraction of these ethers to other accounts on the Ethereum network, including an online exchange wallet if you wanted to turn it into fiat (but I advise against this, you'll want to hold on to those ethers).

Check out this page in the wiki https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API.  Don't worry about installing web3.js or anything you already have all this in your geth console, just skip to the API reference to view commands you can run.

Congrats on your score!